# Why is it that whenever I start the computer the date in my system always is january 2001?

Tags: windows-7

I have a problem in my system, whenever I start the computer the date in my system always is 1 january 2001 and time is 12:00.
When i change the date and time and again start the computer it again become the default date and time mention above.
How can I can change it permanently so that I dont have to change it again and again.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Check your CMOS battery. Likely, it is dead. The CMOS battery is what keeps the BIOS settings saved after each reboot (or power cycle). New ones are available for under $5 in most markets, and are also called Coin Cell batteries (CR2032). Take a look at that, and try replacing it in your motherboard.

If after replacing the battery, or the battery is still spitting out approximately 3.0V when you test with your multimeter, it could indicate a physical problem with the hardware on the motherboard, which would likely require replacing the entire motherboard.

Comment: yeah, the reason it keeps going to that is the system can't save the date, that date in the past is the default in the motherboard.

Comment: Is this the only problem. I mean that I didn't set the date and time properly while installing the windows, shouldn't this be a one of the reason for this.

Comment: Negative, windows will update time on it's own. 12:00 Jan 1 2001 is the default on most motherboards built in the last 10 years.

Comment: nope. This really is the problem. Those things last 5 years at best, and will leak and mess up your motherboard badly. If your time was set wrongly, it would be *incorrect by the same amount* not resetting. If changing the battery didn't help, it may indicate deeper issues, like a broken battery holder, or your computer clock failing.

Comment: Hi all, as soon as I updated my system with the new operating system the date problem is resolved why is that so. I didn't replace any battery nor doing anything with the hardwares just simply install the operating system and its done. Can anybody tell me what is the reason for this now.